# Como utilizo o explode para limitar quais partes de uma string deve aparecer na view?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

Estou tentando utilizar o explode para exibir o primeiro nome de um model currículo, numa tabela na view, inicialmente estava utilizando o método abaixo, mas não funcionou da forma que eu queria, pois só exibiu o nome completo do mesmo model em colunas diferentes. Gostaria de saber como corrigir isso de uma forma que mais se adeque ao que quero.

````
                              @foreach(explode(" ", $registro->nome) as $FirstNome)
                                <td>{{ $FirstNome}}</td>
                              @endforeach
                              @endif ```
````

Comment: Precisa dar uma olhada com mais atenção em como o explode funciona, ele retorna uma matriz... https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.explode.php

Comment: @MagicHat entendi, é que no meu caso só gostaria de pegar o primeiro nome da pessoa, sabe?

Comment: Qual forma eu poderia fazer isso?

Comment: Dá uma estudada nos exemplos da documentação, faz um teste em um script separado para se familiarizar com a função e aí você implementa no seu código.

Answer (score 0):

Olá. Se você que apenas o primeiro nome de uma string, o código `{{ explode(" ", $registro->nome)[0] }}` deve resolver o problema, pois pega o primeiro valor do array retornado pelo `explode`.

Mas acredito que tem um jeito mais elegante de você fazer isso e também reaproveitar o código em outros lugares do código, através de accessors direto na Model.

```
class Registro extends Model 
{
    public function getPrimeiroNomeAttribute()
    {
        $primeiroNome = explode(" ", $this->nome)[0];

        return $primeiroNome;
    }
}
```

E na view:

```
$registro->primeiro_nome
```

Segue a documentação oficial:
https://laravel.com/docs/eloquent-mutators#accessors-and-mutators